# Protobuf Message to JSON conversion of bytes field converts string to base64?

Tags: base64, byte, protobuf.js

I have a proto file like below:

```
syntax = "proto2";
package user;

message user_message {
    required bytes   username = 1;
    optional string   phonenum  = 2;
    optional string   password  = 3;
}
```

When I receive the message, that is serialised as a String from the sender.

This I try to convert to a JSON object:

```
base_msg = msg_periodic_pb2.m_apps_message()
base_msg.ParseFromString(message)
base_msg = json_format.MessageToJson(base_msg)
```

When I print the base_msg, after converting the message to JSON the username gets converted to a base64 string. How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 2):

[This comment](https://github.com/google/protobuf/issues/2801#issuecomment-285812695) on a related GitHub issue answers my question.

> This behavior is actually to be expected, because bytes fields (unlike string fields) can contain non-UTF8 binary data, and since that cannot be directly represented in JSON, we have to base64-encode it.

So, if you really want to have strings. You cannot have the protobuf type as bytes.