# Why protobuf/python do base64 encode for bytes field in MessageToDict function

Tags: python, protocol-buffers

when I use `json_format.MessageToDict` to convert the protobuf message to python dict. the bytes type field will become the base64 encoding.

I find that source code:
https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/github.com/google/protobuf/+/HEAD/python/google/protobuf/json_format.py#289

But why protobuf do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

json cannot keep data in bytes. In order to put bytes inside json, you need something to encode the bytes. base64 is a common method for doing that.

As named, `json_format.MessageToDict`, it converts bytes into base64 encoded string to you.

Similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49358526/protobug-message-to-json-conversion-of-bytes-field-converts-string-to-base64)

Comment: Should be on the documentation!

Comment: I agree the rationale holds for `json_format.MessageToJson` as JSON does not have bytes, they could have use Python bytes() when doing `json_format.MessageToDict`